# Repeat each line using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to duplicate each line of the input using sed. I.e. when the input looks like:

```
first
secod
third
fourth
...
```

I want the output to look like:

```
first first
second second
third third
fourth fourth
... ...
```

and so on.

If this is impossible using sed, then what do you recommend? I prefer the most simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
$ sed 's/.*/& &/' file
first first
second second
third third
fourth fourth
```

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be tailor-made job for `paste` command:

```
paste -d " " file file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use awk,

```
awk '{print $1, $1}' file
```

or as commented, you can do the following in case the words contain white spaces:

```
awk '{print $0, $0}' file
```

Comment: And in case there are whitespaces in the line, you can do `awk '{print $0, $0}' file`

Comment: If you like golf `awk '$0=$0FS$0' file`

Comment: @sudo_O ok, it's fine. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but awk is a bit overkill.